# How to do programmatic indexing on pojos with Infinispan

Tags: infinispan

Pre infinispan-11, we were able to programmatically define indexes for pojos in embedded caches by code that looks like this:

```java
EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().jmx().build());

SearchMapping mapping = new SearchMapping();
mapping.entity(MyData.class).indexed().property("expiry", ElementType.FIELD).field();

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Environment.MODEL_MAPPING, mapping);
properties.put("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "/some/path");

Configuration dcc = cacheManager.getDefaultCacheConfiguration();
ConfigurationBuilder b = new ConfigurationBuilder();
if (dcc != null)
    b = b.read(dcc);
b.indexing().addIndexedEntity(MyData.class).withProperties(properties);
```

However, post infinispan-11, this no longer works. The documentation on the infinispan website is wrong, because it refers to hibernate classes that do not seem to be available any more: https://infinispan.org/docs/14.0.x/titles/query/query.html#programmatic-entity-mapping_query-embedded

Cobbling together what little information there is on both the infinispan and hibernate sites, I now have:

```java
    public static class MySearchMappingConfigurer implements HibernateOrmSearchMappingConfigurer
    {
        @Override
        public void configure(HibernateOrmMappingConfigurationContext context)
        {
            ProgrammaticMappingConfigurationContext mapping = context.programmaticMapping();
            TypeMappingStep dataMapping = mapping.type(MyData.class);
            dataMapping.indexed();
            dataMapping.property("expiry").genericField().projectable( Projectable.YES ).sortable( Sortable.YES );
        }
    }

 System.setProperty("hibernate.search.mapping.configurer", "class:Test.MySearchMappingConfigurer");

EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().jmx().build());

Configuration dcc = cacheManager.getDefaultCacheConfiguration();
ConfigurationBuilder b = new ConfigurationBuilder();
if (dcc != null)
    b = b.read(dcc);
b.indexing().enabled().storage(IndexStorage.FILESYSTEM).path("/some/path")).addIndexedEntity(MyData.class);
Configuration c = b.build();
```

This produces the following error:

> org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000404: The configured entity class MyData is not indexable. Please remove it from the indexing configuration.
>
> at org.infinispan.query.impl.LifecycleManager.checkIndexableClasses(LifecycleManager.java:258)
> at org.infinispan.query.impl.LifecycleManager.cacheStarted(LifecycleManager.java:227)
> at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.notifyCacheStarted(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:354)
> at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:730)
> at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:672)
> at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.internalGetCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:561)
> at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:524)
> at MyTest.test(MyTest.java:90)

Can anybody tell me how to programmatically configure the pojo class `MyData` for indexing for use in an embedded cache?

Comment: For the indexing use case in 14 in embedded, there is an example in the simple tutorials. Have you checked this example? https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/tree/main/infinispan-embedded/query/src/main/java/org/infinispan/tutorial/simple/query

Comment: @karesti your tutorial refers to depends on hibernate annotations. For some generic usage this is not really convenient. Is there any solution without this dependency on hibernate annotation?